# Angular - What is considered safe html?

Tags: wordpress, angularjs, forms, sanitize

I am using Angular together with Wordpress and the plugin JSON api. The post content is filtered through ngSanitize with the ngBindHtml directive. This works good for regular pages and posts but some content gets stuck in the filter, e.g. contact forms. I know that it is possible to bypass the filter when the content is known to be safe, but I am not sure if it is. What is considered safe content and what makes it unsafe?

Comment: any content that comes from a trusted source is safe, and any other content is unsafe.

Comment: For your reading pleasure: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/sce.js,                 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js